# jquery fullscreenchange and on.click Event

Tags: jquery, events, fullscreenchange

I have a slider with responsive video's that can go fullscreen.
When clicked on the poster image in fullscreen mode I want to get the `.clientWidth` of the image to set a div *(.sp-layer)* where the video's iframe is loaded in.

The `fullscreenchange` Events seem to work fine, but whenever I click on the link with the `.on('click')` Event, the fullScreenMode is **undefined**?

```
    this.fullScreenMode = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    console.log("initial fullScreenMode: " + this.fullScreenMode);

    $(document).on('mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function() {
        console.log('fullscreenchange Event fired');
        this.fullScreenMode = !this.fullScreenMode; 
        console.log('fullScreenMode: ' + this.fullScreenMode);

        if (!this.fullScreenMode) {
            console.log('we are not in fullscreen, do stuff');
            $('.sp-layer').css('width', '100%');    
        }
    });

    $('a.sp-video').on('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked on link');
        console.log('fullScreenMode: ' + this.fullScreenMode);

        if (this.fullScreenMode) {
            console.log('we are fullscreen, do stuff');
            var cW = $(this).children('img')[0].clientWidth;
            console.log('clientWidth of image: ' + cW);
            $(this).parent('.sp-layer').css('width', cW);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `this.fullScreenMode` to `document.fullScreenMode` in your click handler. In the click handler, `this` refers to the button `a.sp-video`, not the document.

As in:

```
$('a.sp-video').on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked on link');
    console.log('fullScreenMode: ' + document.fullScreenMode);

    if (document.fullScreenMode) {...
```

Comment: document.fullScreenMode is undefined

Comment: @ChandanKumarThakur check the OP's code, he defines it in the first line